# Types have separate declarations of a private property

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am learning Angular (which is written in TypeScript) and I stumbled upon this error:

**Class 'SnackbarService' incorrectly extends base class 'MatSnackBar'.
Types have separate declarations of a private property '_overlay'.**

when trying to extend `MatSnackBar` from `@angular/material`.

This is my code:

```js
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';
import { Overlay } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
import { LiveAnnouncer } from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
...

export class SnackbarService extends MatSnackBar {

  constructor(
    private _overlay: Overlay, 
    private _liveAnnouncer: LiveAnnouncer,
    ...
  ) {
    super(_overlay, _liveAnnouncer, ...);
    }
  }
}
```

Any help with any type of explanation on why this happens would be really be appreciated.

Comment: It is kind of strange to have a service extend a component!? Although this is not directly about your question it elicited a frown of my eyebrow(s) 

Comment: Just provide the variable names other than the super class's variable names such as "_overlay_1" and "_liveAnnouncer1" and passed them inside the super class constructor:

constructor(
    private _overlay1: Overlay, 
    private _liveAnnouncer1: LiveAnnouncer,
    ...
  ) {
    super(_overlay1, _liveAnnouncer1, ...);
    }

Answer (score 252, accepted):

This happens because by declaring the constructor as taking a `private _overlay` parameter, you have created your own `_overlay`, but that is already defined in the base class `MatSnackBar`.

Remove the `private` part from the declaration and inherit it from the base class. Do the same for the other constructor parameters.

```js
export class SnackbarService extends MatSnackBar{

  constructor(
    _overlay: Overlay, 
    _liveAnnouncer: LiveAnnouncer,
    ...
  ) {
     super(_overlay, _liveAnnouncer, ...);
    }
  }
}
```

You can still access them via `this.`

Comment: In somecases it can be a duplicate property defined in both classes

Comment: In the abstract base class the constructor parameter still can be declared as `private readonly`, but the derived type does need to not have any access modifiers.

Comment: obvious point to make but not stated anywhere above - if you want to use the injected member in the derived class then in the base class the constructor parameter must not be declared private, instead protected typically.

Comment: In my case I had to change the property to `protected` in the parent component to be able to access it in the child component via `this`

Comment: @jjee Yes, marking `protected` fixes the issue. But why is that so? Is there any relevant part of the docs you can share that explains this?

Answer (score 43):

This also happens in cases, were dependencies version mistatch. [From typescript perspective]

For example if your app **A** uses version 1.0 of a package **B**, and version 1.0 of package **C**. However package C uses a different version of package **B**, say 2.0.

Now you have two different classes with same name in overall build process.
To resolve it you must get package C upgraded or package B upgraded, so to have same version accross the App.

Comment: This was my problem.

Comment: Very much this. The dependency typings on mine were all exactly identical and still got this due to a version mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new so I wasn't able to comment on the answer.
I also agree with the approach of using 'protected' instead of 'private' for this use case; rather than just removing the modifier. If you have a parent class and want its properties/methods to be accessible to the child you should use **protected**.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#understanding-protected

Someone in the comments asked why using **protected** fixes the issue. The above URL explains 'why' (in rough terms). It relates to the access modifiers differently affecting property inheritance. If you want a more conceptual reasoning hopefully this helps.

Since **private** declarations are class specific, they cannot be inherited so they never reach the child class. However, they still exist in the parent that the child is inheriting from. So when the child also adds this private variable you end up now with a property duplication when merging the child and parent in the final object (error).

**Protected** is what you want to use because the variable is inherited into the child and they share it now. So even if the child declares it again, they're already sharing it via inheritance so the variables are simply 'merged' together in the final object. All with the same non-public benefits outside the derived class.